# Plotting line graph from pandas DataFrame - does not work if I do not include .mean(), .sum() or even .median(). Very confused

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, linechart

I have a DataFrame that has list of date, city, country, and average temperature in Celcius.
Here is the .info() of this DataFrame:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 16500 entries, 0 to 16499
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------      --------------  -----  
 0   date        16500 non-null  object 
 1   city        16500 non-null  object 
 2   country     16500 non-null  object 
 3   avg_temp_c  16407 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(3)
```

I only want to plot the avg_temp_c for the cities of Toronto and Rome, both lines on one graph. This was actually a practice problem that has the solution, so here is the code for that:

```
toronto = temperatures[temperatures["city"] == "Toronto"]
rome = temperatures[temperatures["city"] == "Rome"]
toronto.groupby("date")["avg_temp_c"].mean().plot(kind="line", color="blue")
rome.groupby("date")["avg_temp_c"].mean().plot(kind="line", color="green")
```

My question is: why do I **need** to include .mean() in lines 3 and 4? I thought the numbers were already in avg_temp_c. Also, I experimented by replacing .mean() with .sum() and .median(), and it gives the same values. However, removing .mean() altogether for both lines just gives a blank plot. I tried to figure why, but I am very confused and I want to understand. Why doesn't it work without .mean() when the values are already listed in avg_temp_c?

I tried removing .mean(). I tried replacing .mean() with .median() and .sum(), which give the exact same values for some reason. I tried just printing toronto["avg_temp_c"] and rome["avg_temp_c"], which gives me the values, but when I plot it without .mean(), .sum(), or .median(), it does not work. I am just trying to figure why this is the case, and how does all three of those methods give me the same values as if I were just to print the avg_temp_c list?

Hope my question was clear. Thank you!

Comment: The code does a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on dates, presumably because there are dates with multiple temps. So for each date, how do you want to combine the multiple values? Pandas needs to know how to aggregate those groups, e.g. [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html), [`groupby.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.median.html), etc. It doesn't make sense to `groupby` with no followup.

Comment: If you want to eliminate the aggregation, you would have to remove the `groupby` as well: `toronto["avg_temp_c"].plot()`

Comment: Also your `date` column seems to be type `object` right now. I would suggest converting the `date` column to `datetime` type before plotting: `toronto["date"] = pd.to_datetime(toronto["date"])`